# Python(Flask) vary hard sort clothing sort

Tags: python

I have json like this:

```
[
    {
        "product_variants": [
            {
                "id": 1669,
"attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "size",
                        "value": "XXS"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "color",
                        "value": "Pink"
                    }
                ]
    },{
                "id": 1670,
"attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "size",
                        "value": "XS"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "color",
                        "value": "Black"
                    }
                ]
    }
     "id": 834,
        "name": "Acute Cardigan"
    }, ....]
```

how i can sort `product_variants` by closing size. Order must to be by size:

```
 SORT_ORDER = ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"]
```

I have only code with output `XXL` etc... If you can give me some advice

```
    for product in products:
        for product_variant in product.product_variants:
            for attribute in product_variant.attributes:
                if attribute['name'].lower() in "size":
                    pring(['attribute']) //print XXL...
```

Comment: where should be size XS and XXS

Comment: @rusu_ro1 thanks for your comment. Yes you are right i need to add all size, but the current example need only for understand how i can to do ordering(all size not important at this moment)

Comment: you have a list with dicts and each dict has product_variants ?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 yes it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dictionary and map all sizes with a value that will be used as the sorting key:

```
SORT_ORDER = {"S" : 0, "M" : 1, "L" : 2, "XL" : 3, "2XL" : 4, "3XL" : 5, "4XL" : 6, "5XL" : 7, "6XL" : 8}
```

Then you can perform sorting, based on the keys of those values:

```
productVariants = [{"product_variants" : sorted(productVariants[0]['product_variants'], key=lambda elem: SORT_ORDER[elem['attributes'][0]['value']])}]
```

For instance:

```
productVariants = [{"product_variants":[{"id":1669,"attributes":[{"name":"size","value":"M"},{"name":"color","value":"Pink"}]},{"id":1670,"attributes":[{"name":"size","value":"S"},{"name":"color","value":"Black"}]}]}]

SORT_ORDER = {"S" : 0, "M" : 1, "L" : 2, "XL" : 3, "2XL" : 4, "3XL" : 5, "4XL" : 6, "5XL" : 7, "6XL" : 8}

productVariants = [{"product_variants" : sorted(productVariants[0]['product_variants'], key=lambda elem: SORT_ORDER[elem["attributes"][0]['value']])}]

print(productVariants)
```

This will return:

```
[{'product_variants': [{'id': 1670, 'attributes': [{'name': 'size', 'value': 'S'}, {'name': 'color', 'value': 'Black'}]}, {'id': 1669, 'attributes': [{'name': 'size', 'value': 'M'}, {'name': 'color', 'value': 'Pink'}]}]}]
```

Comment: Was going to post the same. +1. This solution assumes that the first attribute will **always** be the size though.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar, thanks for the upvote, appreciated. Well, yes, I do assume that the first attribute will always be the size, but the point of the answer was to show an efficient way to sort the product variants. I suppose that the structure of the json file will be the aforementioned. The OP will be able to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

The way to approach this problem is to create a mapping of each size to its position in the sort order.  Then you can pass a key  function to sorted to sort the items.

(This example doesn't handle the json structure, but should be fairly easy to adapt.)

```
>>> import random
>>> SORT_ORDER = ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL"]
>>> order_mapping = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(SORT_ORDER)}
>>> sizes = [random.choice(SORT_ORDER) for _ in range(10)]
>>> sizes
['M', 'S', '2XL', '2XL', '3XL', '3XL', '3XL', 'S', '4XL', '4XL']

>>> sorted(sizes, key=lambda x: order_mapping[x])
['S', 'S', 'M', '2XL', '2XL', '3XL', '3XL', '3XL', '4XL', '4XL']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
from pprint import pprint

my_list = [
    {
        "product_variants": [
            {
                "id": 1669,
"attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "size",
                        "value": "XXS"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "color",
                        "value": "Pink"
                    }
                ]
    },{
                "id": 1670,
"attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "size",
                        "value": "XS"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "color",
                        "value": "Black"
                    }
                ]
    },{
                "id": 1671,
"attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "size",
                        "value": "S"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "color",
                        "value": "Red"
                    }
                ]
    }]}]

SORT_ORDER = ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL", "3XL", "4XL", "5XL", "6XL", "XS", "XXS"]

for item in my_list:
    product_variants = item["product_variants"]
    item["product_variants"] = sorted(product_variants, key=lambda x: SORT_ORDER.index(x['attributes'][0]['value']))


pprint(my_list)
```

output:

```
[{'product_variants': [{'attributes': [{'name': 'size', 'value': 'S'},
                                       {'name': 'color', 'value': 'Red'}],
                        'id': 1671},
                       {'attributes': [{'name': 'size', 'value': 'XS'},
                                       {'name': 'color', 'value': 'Black'}],
                        'id': 1670},
                       {'attributes': [{'name': 'size', 'value': 'XXS'},
                                       {'name': 'color', 'value': 'Pink'}],
                        'id': 1669}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
with open('path_to_file/xx.json') as f:
    x = json.load(f)

sort_order = ['XXXS', 'XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '2XL', '3XL', '4XL', '5XL', '6XL']
order = dict(zip(sort_order, list(range(len(sort_order)))))
p = x[0]['product_variants']
sorted(p, key=lambda item: order[item['attributes'][0]['value']])
```